# How to return values where one value is in both tables but another is in only one?

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables, which look roughly like this:

```
Table1:

 CUSTOMER OFFER SALES
 -------- ----- -----
 A          111     1
 A          222     1
 B          111     1
 B          222     1
 C          111     1


Table2:

 CUSTOMER OFFER
 -------- -----
 A          111
 A          222
 B          111
```

I want to query these tables to return only the customers who are in both tables, but also to only return the rows where that combination of customer & offer does not exist in table2.

In other words, the results should look like this:

```
 CUSTOMER OFFER SALES
 -------- ----- -----
 B          222     1
```

Does anyone know how best to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.customer = t1.customer
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.customer = t1.customer and t2.offer = t1.offer
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` and `EXCEPT` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1 JOIN
(SELECT CUSTOMER, OFFER FROM T1
 WHERE T1.CUSTOMER IN (SELECT T2.CUSTOMER FROM T2)
EXCEPT
SELECT CUSTOMER, OFFER FROM T2) T11
ON T1.CUSTOMER = T11.CUSTOMER AND T1.OFFER = T11.OFFER
```